# Why isn't this perl regex capturing the backreference?

Tags: shell, perl, quoting, rename

I have a directory of files

```
$ ls -1
ep2.mp4
ep3.mp4
ep4.mp4
ep5.mp4
ep6.mp4
ep7.mp4
```

I want to use the perl `rename` utility to make all files look like e.g.

```
ep02.mp4
```

Command I am using

```
rename -n "s/([0-9])/0${1}/" *.mp4
```

current result

```
ep2.mp4 renamed as ep0.mp4
ep3.mp4 renamed as ep0.mp4
ep4.mp4 renamed as ep0.mp4
ep5.mp4 renamed as ep0.mp4
ep6.mp4 renamed as ep0.mp4
ep7.mp4 renamed as ep0.mp4
```

How can I capture the original digit and insert into the new filename?

Comment: You might want to consider something like `'s/([0-9])/sprintf "%02d",$1/e'` as a more general way to zero-pad the digit to the desired width

Comment: Im guess thats more POSIX - which I'm all for - but why would that rather complicated statement be better than a plain `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes (or escape with `\`) around the replacement statement, otherwise shell will treat `${1}` as variable.

So you can do:

```
rename -n 's/([0-9])/0${1}/' *.mp4
```

Or

```
rename -n "s/([0-9])/0\${1}/" *.mp4
```

Comment: ah yes of course - it works :)